# Handle different numbers with dots and colons in Java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have these two values:
Value 1: "33445.0"
Value 2: "33.445,00"

What is the easiest way to see if these two is equal in Java?

I'm struggling with the different types of int, double, float and so on. Now value 1 is stored as double and value 2 is a float.

How can i make these values the same?

Kind regards

Comment: equal after replacing . and ,?

Comment: Replacing will not work because of the different number of zeros after the comma

Comment: This link will give you info about the locale http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569149/understanding-the-strange-output-of-java-util-locale

Comment: Are the numbers you're working with always whole numbers? I would guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the numbers.  The only difference between the two numbers is that they are formatted in different locales

```
NumberFormat format_english = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
NumberFormat format_france = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
Number number1 = format.parse("33445.0");
Number number2 = format.parse("33.445,00");
double d1 = number1.doubleValue();  // or whatever value you're looking for
double d2 = number2.doubleValue();
// now compare them as any two "normal" numbers
```

Now, how do you know which number goes to which Locale?  That's going to be the tricky part.  I'm hoping that you don't get the numbers in without any "extra" information about their origins.

Comment: That is the problem, i don't know witch locale that is used. Is there any list that i can go trough?

Comment: Generally you can't differentiate between "1.000" being 1000 or 1.

Comment: If you don't know which Locale, you're missing some very critical information, as one doesn't know if "biscuit" means a non-sweet tasty scone-like concoction or a cookie without knowing the origin of the word.  The best that you can do is hope that all of your numbers share the same locale, and then deduce which locales could not produce all the numbers in that set.  Even then it won't really give you anything better than an educated guess, which is basically what you're doing.

Comment: You should really be asking - from which Locale did your numbers come from?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the locale of each number, you should at least know the separator (decimal, grouping) characters. Then, you can create a custom [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to parse each.

```
   DecimalFormatSymbols symbols1 = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
   symbols1.setGroupingSeparator(',');
   symbols1.setDecimalSeparator('.');
   DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("0.0", symbols1);
   df1.setParseBigDecimal(true);
   BigDecimal number1 = (BigDecimal) df1.parse("33445.0");

   DecimalFormatSymbols symbols2 = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
   symbols2.setGroupingSeparator('.');
   symbols2.setDecimalSeparator(',');
   DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("0,0", symbols2);
   df2.setParseBigDecimal(true);
   BigDecimal number2 = (BigDecimal) df2.parse("33.445,00");

   int result = number1.compareTo(number2);
```